# undefined method `team_id' - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

The error is undefined method 'team_id' for Player:0x007fb5f41f3838.

I am trying to edit players and I am not able to do that because of an undefined method.

My guess is it has something to do with my relations. I am learning relations between models so they may not be correct.

This is my **Player Model**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_length_of :description, :maximum=>4000

  has_many :descriptions, through: :fouls
  has_many :fouls, as: :foul_by_id
  has_many :fouls, as: :foul_on_id

  belongs_to :team

end
```

This is my **Player Controller**

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :most_recent_fouls


  def index
    @players = Player.all
  end

  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(players_params)
    if @player.save
        redirect_to(:action => "index")
    else
        render("new")
    end
  end

  def edit
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

   def update
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
        if @player.update_attributes(players_params)
            redirect_to(:action => "show", :id => @player.id)
        else
            render("index")
         end
   end

   def destroy
    player = Player.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
   end


   private
   def players_params
        params.require(:player).permit(:name, :number, :position, :bios, :descriptions, :team_id)
   end
 end
```

Because of my gut saying that it has to do with relations, here is my **Team Model**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :players

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

My migration table for **Player**

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players do |p|
       p.string :name
       p.string :number
       p.string :position
       p.string :bio
       p.string :description
       p.integer :team_id
       p.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Please explain your answer. Tell me if you need any more code to be displayed.

Comment: What about a migration for `players` table?

Comment: `belongs_to :team` expects a `team_id` column in your `players` table, but you presumably don't have that. The errors are trying to help you here.

Comment: see edit above @WarHog

Comment: `has_many :fouls, as: :foul_by_id
  has_many :fouls, as: :foul_on_id` not even sure what you are trying to do here but I think you are going to need to `scope` these or set `foreign_keys`. Also why do you have an `attribute` of description and a relationship for `descriptions` this seems very confusing.

Comment: Should `team_id` be a string? `integer` is expected.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have a description of a player and I have a description of a foul.

Comment: @LukeCurran ptd's comment should resolve your actual question but I would suggest making changing the naming conventions used for `descriptions` to something like `foul_descriptions` to avoid confusion as the project grows.

Comment: @engineersmnky how do I set foreign_keys?

Comment: the best way to do this not knowing your keys would be `has_many :fouls, as: :fouls_committed, foreign_key: 'fouled_by_id'` and `has_many :fouls, as: fouls_against, foreign_key: 'foul_on_id'` then it would be `player.fouls_committed` and `player.fouls_against`. This lets rails know how to make the appropriate association of `SELECT fouls.* FROM fouls WHERE fouls.fouled_by_id = some_id`. Does that make sense?